# using --lua option to compile latex file to html fails when including png file with tex4ht and make4ht

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

I am trying to compile a latex document that includes `lua` code with `tex4ht`. I also [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht) to for building latex to html.

According to help on `make4ht` the option `--lua` can be used to compile with lualatex.

The compilation works ok, except when an .png image is included in the document, then it gives an error.   Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}  %is this needed? tried with and without
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
test 
\includegraphics{some_image.png}
\end{document}
```

when the above is compiled using `make4ht -u foo5.tex` then it compiles OK. But when compiled using

```
make4ht --lua  -u foo5.tex
```

then it fails:

```
Compiler:   dvilualatex
Latex options:   -jobname=foo5 
tex4ht.sty :    xhtml,,charset=utf-8
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht))
(./foo5.aux)
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
<read 0> 
   �PNG
l.6 \includegraphics{some_image.png}
```

I also tried

```
 make4ht --lua  foo5.tex
```

The problem shows only when including a .png image.

using TL 2015 64 bits on Linux mint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error probably doesn't have anything in common with `tex4ht`. Try to compile following file with `dvilualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{someimage.png}
\end{document}
```

The error message is the same.

The problem is that `\includegraphics` tries to determine the image bounding box and it reads the file for that information, which works in old 8-bit TeX engines, but it may confuse unicode engines as the image contents can contain values which aren't supported unicode characters. An error is shown for every unsupported character code and this easily exceeds error limit, causing the compilation to fail.

Because `png` images aren't supported in `dvi` mode, it isn't really supposed to work, but when you try to include `png` image in LaTeX, some more meaningful error message is shown:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in someimage.png (no BoundingBox).
```

and at least the document compiles. Maybe this behavior should be used also with `dvilualatex`.

To fix this issue, you can use two ways:

1. Use graphics rules. Try following config file:

   ```
   \Preamble{xhtml}
   \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.jpg,.gif}
   \DeclareGraphicsRule{.png}{bmp}{.xbb}{}
   \DeclareGraphicsRule{.jpg}{bmp}{.xbb}{}
   \DeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{bmp}{.xbb}{}
   \begin{document}
   \EndPreamble
   ```

if you create `.xbb` file for each image with

```
ebb -x imagename
```

then the included images will have even correct dimensions. You can also stop using image extension in the `\includegraphics`, just use:

```
\includegraphics{some_image}
```

2. Use `dvipdfmx` driver for `graphicx` package:

   ```
    \usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
   ```

note that you can't use it when you compile to `pdf`. so you should include it conditionally. Or better, use `make4ht` feature to insert LaTeX code before document inclusion. Use this simple `mk4` file:

```
  Make:htlatex {packages = "\\RequirePackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}"}
```

so you don't have to modify your document now. We have to use `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage` because the code is executed before `\documentclass`.

Regarding `luainputenc`: if you don't need unicode characters, you don't have to use it. Try to compile the document without the package and see if everything works.

Comment: thanks very much! I used your second method, modified my make4ht build file using `\\RequirePackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}` and it works very well. Now the lua code works and the result shows in the HTML which is really very good.