# Problems of .pdf format graphic or image when using htlatex to convert .tex to html

Tags: graphics, pdf, tex4ht, htlatex

Recently I have worked on converting .tex to .html. I have solved a lot of problems with the help of @michal.h21. the last question is about the image problem.

I use the MiKTeX system,  it is basic-miktex-2.9.6361-x64 from [miktex2.9](https://miktex.org/download), and installed on a Windows 7 system.

The code I use is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

The main problem here is as listed: 1, the figure can not be changed well engough, 2 the tabe is also not so good 3, espeially is the refrence list that can not be listed one by one. 
speccial character test.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subfigure[]{
\includegraphics[width=0.45 \textwidth]{pdffigure//AAA.pdf}
\label{AAA}
}
\subfigure[]{
\includegraphics[width=0.45 \textwidth]{pdffigure//BBB.pdf}
\label{BBB}
}
\caption{(a) is the picuture to be tested (b) is the picture to be tested.}
\label{Emission}
\end{figure}


The figure is in figure \ref{AAA}. And also the picuture b is also tested in figure \ref{BBB}. 

\end{document}
```

`pdffigure` is the folder I put all the figures.

I use the command as below

```
htlatex Test.tex
```

However, the figure is not correctly displayed. But if I change the .pdf figures to .eps figures, there will be no errors.

[image]

So the result is like the figure above. I have tried a lot of configuration from stackexchange, but it does work so well. It seems if the system is TeX Live distrubtion, there is no such errors. However, now I used a different system.

PS, this up and down problems could be solved by one post [solving the up and down display](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255826/htlatex-and-subfigures/255842#255842). But still this can not solve the .pdf suffix problem.

Anyone has some suggestions?

Comment: why `//` in `pdffigure//AAA.pdf` ?

Comment: unrelated to images but `\it{\Pi}` `\it` is deprecated, but if you do use it it does not take an argument and by default it has no effect on `\Pi`

Comment: pdffigure is the folder i put all the figures. also it is non related to \it . this command is just a font command. i deleted if this si confusing.  it is about htlatex image .pdf.

Comment: I queried `//` as it is likely to be a syntax error in some filesystems, the syntax should be `/`  .  `\it` is unrelated but the syntax shown above is wrong,so I thought I would mention it.

Comment: thanks for your comment. the thing is if the suffix is .eps, there is no error as indicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PDF` support have been added to `tex4ht` last week, so it should work if you update your TeX distribution. If you can't update it, you can use the following configuration file, which is modified version of the code added to the `tex4ht` core:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\NewConfigure{PdfConvert}{2}
\makeatletter
\catcode`\:=11

\edef\svg@ext{.svg}
\ifx\PictExt\svg@ext
\Configure{PdfConvert}{svg}{"pdf2svg '\Gin@base.pdf' '\Gin@base-\Gin@page.\a:PdfConvert' \Gin@page"}
\else
\Configure{PdfConvert}{png}{"rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 \ifx\Gin@page\@empty\else -dFirstPage='\Gin@page'  -dLastPage='\Gin@page'\fi\space -sOutputFile='\Gin@base-\Gin@page.\a:PdfConvert' \Gin@base.pdf"}
\fi
\Configure{graphics*}
   {pdf}
   {\ifdefined\Gin@page\else\def\Gin@page{1}\fi%
   \Needs{\b:PdfConvert}%
   \edef\svg:filename{\Gin@base-\Gin@page.\a:PdfConvert}
   {\Configure{Needs}{File: \svg:filename}\Needs{}}%
   \Picture[\a:GraphicsAlt]{{\svg:filename} \csname a:Gin-dim\endcsname
}}
\catcode`\:=12
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

It converts `pdf` to `png` by default. It also supports `svg` conversion, which can be requested using the `svg` option, but you need `pdf2svg` command installed on your system for this support.

It is also important to create special files with image dimension for all pictures, in order to get correct size of the images. It can be done using command

```
ebb -x pdffigure/*.pdf
```

This is the result with some dummy images:

[image]

Comment: thanks for you comment again. I have checked my package tex4ht, it is dated 28,May this year. the newest version you mentioned i didn't find it. i also tryed your code listed above, the problem is not solved still.  the image is not displayed, same as the figure in the post.  i have tryed a lot code found on this website, it did not work. a solution would be including in the final stage, only in the .html stage, no matter it is .pdf , .png, .eps etc,making image embed process easier. i attached my log file below with the code you list as above.

Comment: @shqiang it seems that `rungs` command isn't included in Miktex, it also doesn't ship recent version of `tex4ht. Try to replace `rungs` with `gs` in `\Configure{PdfConvert}{png}`.

Comment: i use the package manager and the update to update all the package, still the package is dated 27, july. this is the newest. i found the package you mentioned at https://ctan.org/search/?phrase=tex4ht. but how should i override this package to the system ? after i replace rungs with gs, still gs command is not recognisable.

Comment: @shqiang tex4ht version on CTAN is also outdated, the actual one is included in TeX Live or in the source repository.

Comment: @shqiang it seems that `gs` is named as `mgs` in Miktex

Comment: Thanks greatly! mgs is recognizable. however it has an error like System call: mgs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300  -sOutputFile='pdf
figure//AAA-.png' pdffigure//AAA.pdf
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.19: **** Could not open the file ''pdffigure//AAA-.png''.
Error: /invalidfileaccess in --showpage--
Operand stack:...................  i think i would try to update mk4ht version method. Thanks for all you help!

Comment: @shqiang I thinkt that this error might be caused by your use `//` instead of `/`, it seems that Ghostscript can't find your PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on the "'*rungs' is not recognized*" problem and found that the Ghost Script command varies from one operating system to another. The Linux and Windows commands are:

- Linux: **gs**
- Windows:**mgs**

Also, I realized that it is more appropriate to use the double quoting to define the `-sOutputFIle`, i.e. `"\Gin@base-.\a:PdfConvert"` instead of `'\Gin@base-\Gin@page.\a:PdfConvert'`.
Then the following config file script  worked fine for me on a linux operating system:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\NewConfigure{PdfConvert}{2}
\makeatletter
\catcode`\:=11

\edef\svg@ext{.svg}
\ifx\PictExt\svg@ext
\Configure{PdfConvert}{svg}{"pdf2svg '\Gin@base.pdf' '\Gin@base-\Gin@page.\a:PdfConvert' \Gin@page"}
\else
\Configure{PdfConvert}{png}{"gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 \ifx\Gin@page\@empty\else -dFirstPage='\Gin@page'  -dLastPage='\Gin@page'\fi\space -sOutputFile="\Gin@base-.\a:PdfConvert" \Gin@base.pdf"}
\fi
\Configure{graphics*}
{pdf}
{\ifdefined\Gin@page\else\def\Gin@page{1}\fi%
\Needs{\b:PdfConvert}%
\edef\svg:filename{\Gin@base-\Gin@page.\a:PdfConvert}
{\Configure{Needs}{File: \svg:filename}\Needs{}}%
\Picture[\a:GraphicsAlt]{{\svg:filename} \csname a:Gin-dim\endcsname
}}
\catcode`\:=12
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

With this code in a file named `my.cfg` on the TeX folder you can run:

```
htlatex theTexFile my
```

Hope it could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

i trye michal.h21 code, from prevous lot of posts, it works well for other people. but it did not work on my computer. Add the configure mentioned above, i list the compiling log file below

```
C:\Z Publications\2017\textowordtest>htlatex Fancypattern myhtml.cfg

C:\Z Publications\2017\textowordtest>latex  \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\H
Code\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\els
e\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\Requ
irePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\docu
mentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{
\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatoth
er\HCode myhtml.cfg.a.b.c.\input  Fancypattern
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit)
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
(Fancypattern.tex ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\usepackage.4ht)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\subfigure\subfigure.sty"
****************************************
* Local config file subfigure.cfg used *
****************************************
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\subfigure\subfigure.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\dvips.def"))) (myhtml.cfg
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.4ht
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) (C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty
--- needs --- tex4ht Fancypattern ---
(Fancypattern.tmp) (Fancypattern.xref)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\latex.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\fontmath.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\article.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\subfigure.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\graphicx.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\graphics.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\dvips.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(Fancypattern.aux)) [1] [2]
l.17 --- TeX4ht warning --- Cannot determine size of graphic in pdffigure//Plas
maimage1.pdf (no BoundingBox) ---
l.21 --- TeX4ht warning --- Cannot determine size of graphic in pdffigure//Spat
ialEmissionPPicxorignial.pdf (no BoundingBox) ---
[3] [4] (Fancypattern.aux) )
Output written on Fancypattern.dvi (4 pages, 12364 bytes).
Transcript written on Fancypattern.log.

C:\Z Publications\2017\textowordtest>latex  \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\H
Code\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\els
e\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\Requ
irePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\docu
mentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{
\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatoth
er\HCode myhtml.cfg.a.b.c.\input  Fancypattern
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit)
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
(Fancypattern.tex ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\usepackage.4ht)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\subfigure\subfigure.sty"
****************************************
* Local config file subfigure.cfg used *
****************************************
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\subfigure\subfigure.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\dvips.def"))) (myhtml.cfg
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.4ht
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) (C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty
--- needs --- tex4ht Fancypattern ---
(Fancypattern.tmp) (Fancypattern.xref)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\latex.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\fontmath.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\article.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\subfigure.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\graphicx.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\graphics.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\dvips.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(Fancypattern.aux)) [1] [2]
l.17 --- TeX4ht warning --- Cannot determine size of graphic in pdffigure//Plas
maimage1.pdf (no BoundingBox) ---
l.21 --- TeX4ht warning --- Cannot determine size of graphic in pdffigure//Spat
ialEmissionPPicxorignial.pdf (no BoundingBox) ---
[3] [4] (Fancypattern.aux) )
Output written on Fancypattern.dvi (4 pages, 12364 bytes).
Transcript written on Fancypattern.log.

C:\Z Publications\2017\textowordtest>latex  \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\H
Code\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\els
e\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\Requ
irePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\docu
mentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{
\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatoth
er\HCode myhtml.cfg.a.b.c.\input  Fancypattern
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit)
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
(Fancypattern.tex ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\usepackage.4ht)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\subfigure\subfigure.sty"
****************************************
* Local config file subfigure.cfg used *
****************************************
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\subfigure\subfigure.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\dvips.def"))) (myhtml.cfg
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.4ht
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) (C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty
--- needs --- tex4ht Fancypattern ---
(Fancypattern.tmp) (Fancypattern.xref)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\latex.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\fontmath.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\article.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\subfigure.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\graphicx.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\graphics.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\dvips.4ht
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht)
(C:\Users\zhang\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht))
(Fancypattern.aux)) [1] [2]
l.17 --- TeX4ht warning --- Cannot determine size of graphic in pdffigure//Plas
maimage1.pdf (no BoundingBox) ---
l.21 --- TeX4ht warning --- Cannot determine size of graphic in pdffigure//Spat
ialEmissionPPicxorignial.pdf (no BoundingBox) ---
[3] [4] (Fancypattern.aux) )
Output written on Fancypattern.dvi (4 pages, 12364 bytes).
Transcript written on Fancypattern.log.

C:\Z Publications\2017\textowordtest>tex4ht Fancypattern  -i/tex4ht/ht-fonts/ -e
win32/tex4ht.env
----------------------------
tex4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:36 Windows MiKTeX)
tex4ht Fancypattern
  -i/tex4ht/ht-fonts/
  -ewin32/tex4ht.env
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/base/win32/tex4ht.env)
(C:/Users/zhang/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/iso8859/1/charset/uni
code.4hf)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr12.tfm)
(C:/Users/zhang/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/lm/lm-rep-cmrm/
cmr.htf)
Searching `lm-rep-cmrm.htf' for `cmr12.htf'
(C:/Users/zhang/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/lm/lm-rep-cmr
m.htf)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm)
(C:/Users/zhang/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/lm/lm-rep-cmrm/
cmr.htf)
Searching `lm-rep-cmrm.htf' for `cmr10.htf'
(C:/Users/zhang/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/lm/lm-rep-cmr
m.htf)
[1 file Fancypattern.html
 file Fancypattern.css
 file Fancypattern.tmp
] [2] [3] [4]
Execute script `Fancypattern.lg'

C:\Z Publications\2017\textowordtest>t4ht Fancypattern  -ewin32/tex4ht.env
----------------------------
t4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:28 MiKTeX)
t4ht Fancypattern
  -ewin32/tex4ht.env
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/base/win32/tex4ht.env)
Entering Fancypattern.lg
Entering Fancypattern.css
Entering Fancypattern.tmp
System call: rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 -dFirstPage='1'
-dLastPage='1' -sOutputFile='pdffigure//Plasmaimage1-1.png' pdffigure//Plasmaima
ge1.pdf
'rungs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
--- Warning --- System return: 1
System call: rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 -dFirstPage='1'
-dLastPage='1' -sOutputFile='pdffigure//SpatialEmissionPPicxorignial-1.png' pdff
igure//SpatialEmissionPPicxorignial.pdf
'rungs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
--- Warning --- System return: 1

C:\Z Publications\2017\textowordtest>
```

the mythml.cfg file containing the code mentioned above