# Using subfigure with tex4ht

Tags: subfloats, tex4ht, tex4ebook

i've read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255826/htlatex-and-subfigures) question and the subfigure environment works fine, except captions aren't centered below the images. Instead, it looks like this: 
[image]

is there a way to fix this?
my config.cfg looks like this so far:

```
\let\origincludegraphics\includegraphics
\Preamble{xhtml,pic-tabular}


\Configure{HtmlPar}
{\EndP\Tg<p>}
{\EndP\Tg<p>}
{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}
{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}


\Configure{picture}
{\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}\Picture+[PICT]{}}
{\EndPicture}

%%%Images

\Configure{graphics*}
    {jpg}
    {%  
       \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .jpg
          \space width="\the\dimexpr \expandafter\csname
Gin@req@width\endcsname *2"
}%  
      \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.jpg}
     }
\Configure{graphics*}
    {png}
    {%  
       \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .png
          \space width="\the\dimexpr \expandafter\csname
Gin@req@width\endcsname *2"
}%  
      \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}
     }


\Configure{graphics*}
{eps}
{%  
\openin15=\csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt\relax 
  \ifeof15 
  \Needs{"convert \csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps 
    \csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt"}% 
  \fi 
  \closein15 
   \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname \PictExt
      \space width="\the\dimexpr \expandafter\csname
Gin@req@width\endcsname *1.5"
}%  
  \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt}
 }


\Configure{Picture*}{\let\includegraphics\origincludegraphics}{}
\Configure{Picture+}{\let\includegraphics\origincludegraphics}{}



%%%%%%Subfigure

\ConfigureEnv{subfigure}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="subfigure">}}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
\Css{.subfigure{display: inline-block;}}
\Css{.subfigure img{display:block;}}

\Css{.figure div.caption{text-align: center;}}
\Css{div.figure{text-align:center;clear:both;overflow:auto;width:100\%;margin-bottom:1em;}}

%%%%%MINIPAGE

\makeatletter
\def\striptextwidth#1\textwidth{#1}
\newcount\mini@count
\let\oldiimini\@iiiminipage
\def\@iiiminipage#1#2[#3]#4{%
\xdef\miniwidth{\strip@pt\dimexpr(\striptextwidth#4pt)*100\relax\%}
\oldiimini{#1}{#2}[#3]{#4}
}

\ConfigureEnv{minipage}{\advance\mini@count by 1\relax\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="minipage" align="center" id="minipage\the\mini@count">}}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>\Hnewline}%
\Css{\#minipage\the\mini@count{width:\miniwidth;}}%
}{}{}
\makeatother
\Css{div.minipage {
 float: left; 
 } 
}
\Css{div.minipage:last-child {
 clear: none; 
 float: right; 
 }
}
\Css{div.figure{clear:both;overflow:auto;width:100\%;max-width:100\%;height:auto;}}


\begin{document}
\CssFile[custom.css] 
/* css.sty */
\EndCssFile
\Configure{CoverMimeType}{image/jpg}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.png,.jpg,.gif,}
\EndPreamble
```

edit: this problem only occurs when the caption is too long. A workaround is to force a line break manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subfigure just needs to be correctly styled using the CSS styles. It needs to have maximum width set, as it would grow without break otherwise. Try these definitions:

```
\Css{.subfigure{display: inline-block;max-width:30\%;}}
\Css{.subfigure img{display:block; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}}
```

The `max-width` property depends on number of subfigures you use, you will need to play with different percentages to find the best value.

It may look in this way:

[image]