# tex4ebook subfigures: (1) side-by-side subfigures (2) styling changes when .tex inserted with \include

Tags: graphics, subfloats, tex4ht, include, tex4ebook

I'm using tex4ebook to generate an epub. I want subfigures to be placed side-by-side with subcaptions below the subfigures. I came across a couple of issues and I'd appreciate any hints for how to resolve them.

**How do I get side-by-side subfigures?**

I used recommendations in the answers to these questions to configure and provide css for figures and subfigures: [htlatex and subfigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255826/htlatex-and-subfigures)

[htlatex and subfigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255826/htlatex-and-subfigures)
[Using subfigure with tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456845/using-subfigure-with-tex4ht)

This is part of the result I got. The other part is a pair of subfigures that are identical except for the captions.
[image]

mwe.cfg

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\ConfigureEnv{figure}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="figure">}%
    \bgroup \Configure{float}{\ShowPar}{}{}%
   }
   {\egroup
    \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}\ShowPar
\par}
{}{}

\Css{div.caption{text-align:center;font-size:83\%;text-indent:0em;margin-left:2em;margin-right:2em;}}
\Css{div.figure{text-align:center;clear:both;overflow:auto;width:100\%;margin-bottom:1em;}}

\ConfigureEnv{subfigure}
    {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode
    {<div class="subfigure"\Hnewline>}}
    {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}
{}{}

\Css{div.subfigure {text-align:center;display:inline-block; max-width:45\%;}}
\Css{.subfigure img{display:block; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}}

\ConfigureEnv{subfigurecaption}
    {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="subfigurecaption">}}
    {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}
{}{}

\Css{.subfigcaption {margin-top:1em;margin-left:1em;}}

\makeatletter 
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.svg,.png}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\Configure{Gin-dim}
    {style="width:\fp_eval:n{round(\Gin@req@width/\textwidth*100,2)}\%;max-height:\fp_eval:n{round(\Gin@req@height/\textwidth*100,2)}\%;"}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

mwe.tex

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\include{included}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{A pair of frogs}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\caption{Third Frog}
\label{fig:frogone}
\includegraphics[width=0.36\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{./images/simplefrog.png}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\caption{Fourth Frog}
\label{fig:frogtwo}
\includegraphics[width=0.36\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{./images/simplefrog.png}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

included.tex

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{Included frogs}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.36\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{./images/simplefrog.svg}
    \caption{First Frog}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.36\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{./images/simplefrog.svg}
    \caption{Second Frog}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

When I commented out `\Css{.subfigure img{display:block; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}}` the figures are scaled correctly, but the styling when the subfigures are inserted in the top-level .tex file is different from the styling when they're inserted with \include (the subcaption is beside the subfigure instead of being under it).

That leads me to my second question:

**What can I do ensure the styling of subfigures doesn't change when they're inserted with \include?**

Here's what the .epub looks like when I comment out the line I mentioned (css for subfigure img) in the .cfg:

[image]

mwe.html

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> 
<head>
   <title></title> 
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' /> 
<meta name='generator' content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' /> 
<meta name='originator' content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' /> 
<!--  charset=utf-8,epub,uni-html4,html,xhtml  --> 
<meta name='src' content='mwe.tex' /> 
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='mwe.css' /> 
</head><body>

   <div class='figure'>


<a id='x1-2r1'></a>
<a id='x1-3'></a>
<br />                                                                  <div class='caption'><span class='id'>
Figure 1: </span><span class='content'>Included frogs
</span></div><!-- tex4ht:label?: x1-2r  -->
<div class='subfigure'><!-- l. 7 --><p class='noindent'><img alt='PIC' src='./images/simplefrog.png' style='width:36%;max-height:36%;' /> <a id='x1-4r1'></a>
<span class='cmr-9'>(a) First Frog</span>
</p></div> <div class='subfigure'><img alt='PIC' src='./images/simplefrog.png' style='width:36%;max-height:36%;' /> <a id='x1-5r2'></a>
<span class='cmr-9'>(b) Second Frog</span>
</div>

   </div>


   <div class='figure'>


<a id='x1-6r2'></a>
<a id='x1-7'></a>
<br />                                                                  <div class='caption'><span class='id'>
Figure 2: </span><span class='content'>A pair of frogs
</span></div><!-- tex4ht:label?: x1-6r  -->
<div class='subfigure'><a id='x1-8r1'></a>
<!-- l. 14 --><p class='noindent'><span class='cmr-9'>(a) Third Frog</span>
</p><!-- l. 16 --><p class='noindent'><img alt='PIC' src='./images/simplefrog.png' style='width:36%;max-height:36%;' />
</p></div> <div class='subfigure'><a id='x1-9r2'></a>
<span class='cmr-9'>(b) Fourth Frog</span>
<!-- l. 21 --><p class='noindent'><img alt='PIC' src='./images/simplefrog.png' style='width:36%;max-height:36%;' />
</p></div>

   </div>   
 
</body></html>
```

Comment: I've tried your TeX and configuration files and everything looks correctly in Firefox. Sunfigures are displayed one next to other.

Comment: I tried my .tex and config file again and the scaling is correct, but the figures are still stacked rather than side-by-side, and the captions of the subfigures inserted with \include are still beside the subfigures rather than appearing beneath them. I took a look at the html file in firefox and the epub and zathura and the positioning of the subfigures and subcaptions is the same in both.

Comment: the captions and pictures are in the order you put them. in the included file you have captions after graphics, in the main tex file you have captions and then graphics.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I corrected my included.tex file and the subcaptions are positioned correctly, but the subfigures are still not side-by-side. I compiled the document using the config file you suggested below. Although when I compiled with the config and tex files I included in my question, for some reason now they're producing the correct output. Perhaps there's something else I'm overlooking.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another version of the .cfg file. I hope it works now,.

Comment: Thank you! I just had to make one small adjustment to get subfigure captions to appear under the subfigure rather than to the side. I added this line to the .cfg file: \Css{.subfigure img{display:block; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration file works for me. I would change it a bit though. First of all, we can add a configuration file for the `subcaption` package, `subcaption.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{subfigure}{2}
\ConfigureEnv{subfigure}{\a:subfigure}{\b:subfigure}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{subtable}{\a:subfigure}{\b:subfigure}{}{}
\Hinput{subcaption}
```

It defines new configuration hooks `subfigure`. You can modify the `.cfg` file to use that:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\ConfigureEnv{figure}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="figure">}%
    \bgroup \Configure{float}{\ShowPar}{}{}%
   }
   {\egroup
    \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}\ShowPar
\par}
{}{}

\Configure{subfigure}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP%
     \HCode{<div class="subfigure">}\par\ShowPar
}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}

\Css{figure.float, div.figure {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align:center;}}
\Css{figure.float img, figure.figure img {display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}}
\Css{figure.figure {text-align:center;}}
\Css{figcaption.caption, div.caption  {text-indent:-2em; margin-left:3em; margin-right:1em; text-align:center;}}
\Css{figcaption.caption span.id{font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap; }}
\Css{div.subfigure {text-align:center;display:inline-block; max-width:45\%;}}

\makeatletter 
\ExplSyntaxOn
 \Configure{Gin-dim}
     {style="width:\fp_eval:n{round(\Gin@req@width/\textwidth*100,2)}\%;max-height:\fp_eval:n{round(\Gin@req@height/\textwidth*100,2)}\%;"}
 \ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same output (stacked subfigures and subcaptions for first set of subfigures appear to the side of the figures).